# cAdvisor custom metrics with heapster format

Tags: kubernetes, heapster, cadvisor

I currently have a Kubernetes cluster configured with Heapster/InfluxDB/Grafana.

I know that the Kubelet now has an embedded cAdvisor instance that I have configured to look at an application endpoint to gather custom metrics.

I followed this guide: http://guoshimin.github.io/2016/06/03/custom-metrics.html:

```
{
  "endpoint" : "http://localhost:31234/sessions",
  "metrics_config" : [
    {
      "name" : "activeSessions",
      "metric_type" : "gauge",
      "units" : "number of active sessions",
      "data_type" : "int",
      "polling_frequency" : 10,
      "regex" : "Active sessions: ([0-9]+)"
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently the Kubelet is throwing the error -

```
failed to create collector for container "/docker/664af6c4c1998514770371267ba6c117c532a448f6301f14fc53ca9798abff5b", config "prometheus": json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type string
```

It seems to think that I am using a Prometheus config. Is there a different format I should use in order for it to collect metrics and pass them to Heapster since I do not have Prometheus in my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes currently only supports gathering custom metrics in the Prometheus format. Your configuration is for a generic collector, so the prometheus collector isn't able to parse it.

As an experiment, you could manually change the docker label on the container running on the host from `io.cadvisor.metric.prometheus` to `io.cadvisor.metric.raw`, and it should work. There is no mechanism in Kubernetes to do this automatically though.

Once cAdvisor has scraped the custom metrics, they are then exported in a format the Heapster understands. As long as cAdvisor is able to get the metrics, Heapster will be able to get the metrics from cAdvisor.